# How do I download a file by knowing the file name only using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, download

I am trying to download a file using jQuery. The problem is I have no reference about the file extension. I only know the file name. The file name is unique because it shares the same name with the primary key. So, no file is the same.

This is the jQuery I use:

```
$("#tbl_surat_all tbody").on('click','.row_surat', function(e) {
    var no_s    = $(this).find('a').html(); //get the file name
    var b_url   = $('#base_url').val()+"assets/uploads/surat/"; //base_url

    var url     = b_url+no_s; //download_url

    window.location = url; //script_to_download
});
```

How do I download the file by only knowing the file name??

Note:

- I have no privilage to change table structure, so I can't update the upload script.
- The file are images, pdfs, and rars

Comment: use php to run a glob search on the directory

Comment: um, I do not want to check a file is exist or not, I'd like to download it.

Comment: you cant download it till you find it, and you cant find it with js alone, and you cant find it with out knowing the full file name. theses are files on the server -right?

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.href = file_url` ?

Comment: @DevendraLattu yes. but without extension, it displays 404 not found as if no t page found

Comment: What type of file are you expecting to be at URL?

Comment: @guest271314 png, jpg, jpeg, rar, and pdf

Comment: really the only sensible solution is to know the actual file name in the first place- why can you 'fix' that?

Comment: @nogad I have no privileges dealing with the uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to open the file from the server without sending a valid request.

If you don't request the complete file name with extension, you will get an error.

So the only workaround would be to request all possible file extensions.

We could try to include the following:

```
.jpeg .jpg .png .pdf .rar
```

And then iterate it with requests.

Since this would open a **** load of windows, we will be immediately closing them, so it will look relatively smooth.

Here is the code:

```
var url_base='http://127.0.0.1/base_url/file_without_extension';
var ext_arr=['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.pdf', '.rar'];

for (i=0;i<ext_arr.length;i++){
    var url=url_base+ext_arr[i];
    window.open(url)
        .addEventListener('load', function(){
            this.close();
    }, false);
}
```

Note: do note that in order for it work properly, requested files must meet the same origin policy.

**Edit:** I have modified the above code to load resources in background via xhttp requests and then output it directly for download.

This method should work flawlessly for **all types of files**, and it's also the fastest!

```
var url_base='http://127.0.0.1/';
var file_name='file_without_extension';
var ext_arr=['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.pdf', '.rar'];


for (i=0;i<ext_arr.length;i++){
    // Define request url
    var url=url_base+file_name+ext_arr[i];
    // Use XMLHttpRequest instead of Jquery $ajax
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Set the url as a property
    xhttp['user_filename']=file_name;
    // Bind on ready function
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var a;
        // Check if page has loaded successfully
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            // Trick for making downloadable link
            a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
            // Filename for downloading
            a.download = this.user_filename;
            a.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
        }
    };
    // Set request url and method
    xhttp.open("GET", url);
    // Set responseType as blob for binary response
    xhttp.responseType = 'blob';
    // Send request
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I do not know why, but the pdf opened this way act if it's damaged.